# AudioToolBox: When do I dispose the system sound object, and why do I need to dispose it?

Tags: swift, swift4, audiotoolbox

I am using AudioToolBox to make a xylophone app, and came across a library called AudioToolBox.
Copy and pasting from some of the code in stackoverflow, I was able to understand and play sounds on my xylophone app using the code below.

```
func playSound(senderTag : Int) {
     if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "note\(senderTag)", withExtension: "wav") {
     var mySound: SystemSoundID = 0
     AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL as CFURL, &mySound)
     // Play
     AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(mySound); 
}
```

However, I am looking through the Apple's Developers Documentation, and found a function 
`func AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(SystemSoundID) -> OSStatus`
Which says that "Disposes of a system sound object and associated resources."
When do I have to use this function, and why would I need to use this function?

Comment: Because without it there is a leak. You have manual memory management responsibility here.

Comment: Thanks!
Learned about memory management recently so I got it know

Comment: You might want to read the explanation in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management

Comment: Thank you very much!! Will definitely look through it.